# Items overlapping in Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The Items in my recycler view are overlapping when user scrolls.  Notice the overlapping text at the bottom:

[image]

Here is the code generating this view:

```
        ArrayList<Bitmap> drawables = mBitmaps;
        RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(ctx);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(ctx);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(contentList, uriList, drawables);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        ((ViewGroup) rootView).addView(recyclerView);
```

- `mBitmaps` is a set of images
- `contentList` is a list of strings
- `uriList` is another list of strings

Here is the code of `MyRecyclerAdapter` class :

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<String> mContentList, mUriList;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> mBitmaps;
    MyRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<String> contentList, ArrayList<String> uriList, ArrayList<Bitmap> drawables){
        mContentList = contentList;
        mUriList = uriList;
        mBitmaps = drawables;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final Context ctx = parent.getContext();
        CardView.LayoutParams params = new CardView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        CardView cardView = new CardView(ctx);
        cardView.setLayoutParams(params);

        // set edges round for the cardView
        int radius = 14;
        final float scale = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int pixels = (int) (radius * scale + 0.5f);
        cardView.setRadius(pixels);

        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(cardView);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Context ctx = holder.itemView.getContext();
        View view = getViewForCard(ctx, position);      // getView for the card
        holder.viewGroup.addView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mBitmaps.size();
    }

    public View getViewForCard(Context context, int pos){

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Context ctx = context;
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(ctx);
        ll.setLayoutParams(params);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        TextView tv = new TextView(ctx);
        tv.setText(mUriList.get(pos));
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(ctx);
        tv1.setText(mContentList.get(pos));

        // create an image view and add bitmap to it.
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(ctx);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 500;
        imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 500;
        imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmaps.get(pos));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        ll.addView(imageView);       
        ll.addView(tv);                 ll.addView(tv1);

        return ll;
    }

}
```

And here is my `ViewHolder` class:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ViewGroup viewGroup;

    MyViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        viewGroup = (ViewGroup)itemView;
    }
}
```

To reiterate the problem, **how can I prevent the overlapping seen in the image?**

Comment: Please include the image in the question body itself, and indicate specifically where the problem is.

Comment: @kdbanman, I have provided the link please visit. I cann't post an image since I am new to stack and thus doesn't have enough reputation. :(

Comment: Sorry - I didn't realize that was blocked by reputation.  I've made the edit myself.  If the edit passes peer review then you should see it soon.

Comment: great @kdbanman, thanks a lot for the edit. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Context ctx = holder.itemView.getContext();
    View view = getViewForCard(ctx, position);      // getView for the card

    holder.viewGroup.removeAllViews();     // **The problem solved here**

    holder.viewGroup.addView(view);
}
```

I removed all views from the `holder.viewGroup` in the `onBindViewHolder()` method within `MyRecyclerAdapter` class. And there is no more overlapping :).

Comment: You could just reuse your ImageView instead of recreating it each time it bound to.  This definitely decreases performance.

Comment: I agree with @Submersed, because it's called a `RecyclerView` but you're doing the opposite of recycling views.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot. I am creating views dynamically and removeAllViews fixed my issue!